# MVVM project. How to connect Model View to the View

Tags: swift, xcode, api, mvvm, network-programming

I am trying to make an app that will show the weather in my city. I am using MVVM architecture and I have my Model, ModelView and View as follows. I have a variable inside the WeatherModelView class that I want to use in my view controller:

label.text = "(weatherViewModel.res?.main.temp ?? -123)"

but it does not work.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BTEJ.png)
[View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCHG6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW54n.png)

It does not give an error, it simply prints -123.0 on the label, which is the nil case after unwrapping. I would like it to print the actual weather. I don't think there are problems with the URL or the JSON decoding.

This is what is wrongfully shown when I run it:  [simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBcsw.png)

Comment: Always include code as text and not as images.

Answer (score 0):

In "viewdidload" "fetchWeather" is not complete.
You need set "label.text"  after it completed

change res in your view model

```
var res = WeatherModel? {
   didSet {
     resHasData?()
   }
}
var resHasData?: (() -> Void)?
```

add my code in the last line "viewDidLoad"

```
weatherViewModel.resHasData = { [weak sekf] in
    guard let self = self else { return } 
    self.label.text = "\(self.weatherViewModel.res?.main.temp ?? -123)"
}
```

good luck.

Comment: I pretty much inserted your code but i am getting 4 errors in the view model class.

1)Expected member name or constructor call after type name
2-3-4) Type annotation missing in pattern

Comment: OK, I got it to have no errors, by adding your code. But now nothing is showing up on the simulator, its just a blank screen

Comment: maybe temp your api response is "". Have you checked the api with post man?